# Имитация автоклика мышью с рандомной задержкой

Tags: javascript

Как сделать имитацию автоклика мыши, с некоторой рандомной задержкой времени, например от 5 до десяти секунд на странице сайта с помощью javascript или другого языка программирования?

Например, это будет клик по ссылке или просто клик в любом месте сайта.

Comment: selenium/phantomjs в помощь.

Comment: @Bor, Вам нужен JavaScript или JavaFX? это две совершенно разные технологии. JavaFX - это аналог flash'а на Java.  Java и JavaScript это два совершенно разных языка. Удалите метку `javafx` и добавьте метку `javascript`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click

Comment: Ok, желательно java,  хотя пойдут и другие языки, главное чтобы работало.

Comment: с задержкой времени, автоклик, у меня были исходники таких скриптов, но я переустанавливал виндовс, удалил весь архив который долго собирал, вот теперь ищу в рунете и англоязычном пространстве,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На JavaScript

```js
var secs = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], // секунды задержки
  delay = secs[Math.floor(Math.random() * secs.length)], // рандомное значение из массива
  link = document.getElementById('link');
console.log('Задержка - ' + delay + ' секунд'); // для демонстрации

setTimeout(function() {
  link.click(); // имитируем клик
  console.log('Клик'); // для демонстрации
}, delay * 1000); // 1000 - миллисекунды
```

```html
<a href="/goToPath/" id="link">Link</a>
```

Без комментариев и остального "мусора" все это можно сократить до следующего кода:

```js
var secs = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('link').click();
}, secs[Math.floor(Math.random() * secs.length)] * 1000);
```

```html
<a href="/goToPath/" id="link">Link</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, протестирую и отпишусь позже.

Comment: Все отлично работает, вставил  скрипт в java на страницу сайта! Good working!

Comment: Ok. Все отметил, не сразу сообразил где эта галочка, вот теперь все, отметил ответ принял ! Ок.